# How to name File objects and their corresponding path strings in Java

Tags: java, naming-conventions

Often times, I find myself creating two objects like these:

```
String pathString = "/foo/bar";
File path = new File(pathString);
```

Though variable naming is a fairly subjective issue, what's the most common naming convention for `File` objects and their corresponding absolute file path stored in a `String`?

Comment: I don't think there's a universally accepted convention, though certain projects may have their own. In this particular case I'd either call the first variable `pathName` or get rid of it altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there is no naming convention. I would either take a look at the [constructor argument of File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File(java.lang.String)) and name it after that, e.g.

```
String pathname = "/foo/bar";
File file = new File(pathname);
```

Normally the file has a meaning in your application. So I would choose a name that describes it. E.g.

```
String errorLogFilepath = "/var/log/error.log";
File errorLogFile = new File(errorLogFilepath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to idependently identify the path?

If not, Id suggest just using:

```
File path = new File("/foo/bar");
```

Similarly, pass around File objects, not string paths.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not reusing this path for further reference in the code , suggest you to initialize the file by passing an arguement. eg

```
File file = new File("/foo/bar");
```

This will prevent the creation of an extra string variable.

Answer (score 0):

I always use double backslash and I've never have problem with that:

```
File outputfile = new File("c:\\Selenium\\workspace\\....\\input.txt");
```